# Why does this loop return NULL

Tags: r, loops, gsub

I would like to replace specific string in an URL 
so I will get a data frame's columns of links per each "job".It seems 
that I have a problem with my loop .How can I solve 
this problem?

```
        dat <- read.table(text = "  Index          job          age            
                                         44        DBA            0      
                                         55        SAS            0      
                                         66        CLOUD          0      
                                         77        AJAX           0      
                                         88        C              1      
                                         99        FULLSTACK      1  ", header = TRUE)

    dat1<-as.list(dat[[2]])
    url  = "'as/DD/p=DD"
    test <-gsub('DD',dat1[[1]],url,ignore.case = T)   # checking the gsub result manually
    test
    #[1] "'as/DBA/p=DBA"    #this is correct

#Now inside a loop    
    s<- for (i in 1:length(dat1)){
            test <-gsub('DD',dat1[[1]],url,ignore.case = T)
         }
    s
    > s
    NULL
```

Why do I get "Null" instead the following desired outcome:

```
    as/DBA/p=DBA
    as/SAS/p=SAS            
    as/CLOUD/p=CLOUD
    as/AJAX/p=AJAX
    as/C/p=C
    as/FULLSTACK/p=FULLSTACK
```

Comment: `for` in R return nothing you can try `s<-lapply(1:length(dat1),function(i){gsub('DD',dat1[[i]],url,ignore.case = T)})`

Comment: or `lapply(dat1, function(i) gsub('DD',i,url,ignore.case = T))`. Change to `sapply` to obtain a vector rather than list

Comment: I tried both line codes but I get strange outcome(here is firstline example):"'as/'as/'as/'as/DBA/p=DBA/p='as/DBA/p=DBA/p='as/'as/DBA/p=DBA/p='as/DBA/p=DBA/p='as/'as/'as/DBA/p=DBA/p='as/DBA/p=DBA/p='as/'as/DBA/p=DBA/p='as/DBA/p=DBA"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not saving your result anywhere. If you change the loop so that it selects the appropriate list element and save the outcome to list it should give you what you want.

```
for (i in 1:length(dat1)){
  test <-gsub('DD',dat1[[i]],url,ignore.case = T)
  dat1[[i]] <- test
}
```

Comment: @mql4beginner it works for me. Type `dat1` and you will see all output links

Comment: Thanks, @USER_1, please consider adding this line of code to your answer: data.frame(matrix(unlist(dat1), byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Comment: I am not sure why is it necessary? In fact, rather than converting dat to list,  you could do the loop directly on dat, by using this subsetting inside the loop - dat[i,2]

Comment: The line of code I proposed will create the desired data frame.